# How to generate 32-bit dll from a C git repo

Tags: c, git, visual-studio, dll, cmake

I need to build a 32bit dll from JWT C language implementation

Git repo https://github.com/GlitchedPolygons/l8w8jwt

I have tried to use the default cmake "build.sh" in the git project but it generates  64-bit dll.

How can I change it to make 32bit dll OR use Visualstudio to generate the 32-bit dll?

I am new at this so kindly dont mind if my question is naive :)

Br,

Comment: That's not here that you should ask but better on the project github. Open an issue to ask. But perhaps building a 32bit dll is not supported....

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned this project might not support 32-bit (some projects make that decision).

However if it does support 32-bit here's how you do it.

For gcc platforms add this to the configure command

```
cmake -S . -B build ... -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-m32 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m32
```

For visual studio it's a bit different, I'm gonna post an example for vs2019

```
cmake -S . -B build ...  -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32
```

Btw consider making a pull request with explicit instructions for 32-bit (if they want to)